# Running Docker image cause an Kestrel Exception

Tags: c#, asp.net, docker, jenkins

I`m facing strange behavior when i try to run my docker image in Linux OS - the image contains .Net core Web API project

Here is my Program.cs

```
 var host = new WebHostBuilder()
.UseKestrel().UseStartup<Startup>().Build();
 host.Run();
```

My Docker-compose.yml file

```
version: '2'
services:
server:
    image: repo.testCompany.com:1443/testCompany:6
    ports:
    - "60000:60000"
    hostname: ucp.${HOST_HOSTNAME}
    restart: unless-stopped
```

The image is build and push successfully.The problem came when the Web API is try to run the project inside the container,and runtime exception is thrown -

```
Unhandled Exception: System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. 
(Error -99 EADDRNOTAVAIL address not available) ---> 
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Internal.Networking.UvException: Error 
-99 EADDRNOTAVAIL address not available
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Internal.Networking.Libuv.Check(Int32 
statusCode)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Internal.Networking.Libuv.tcp_bind(UvTcpHandle handle, SockAddr& addr, Int32 flags)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Internal.Networking.UvTcpHandle.Bind(ServerAddress address)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Internal.Http.TcpListener.CreateListenSocket()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Internal.Http.Listener.<>c.<StartAsync>b__6_0(Object state)
 --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean includeTaskCanceledExceptions)
at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait(Int32 millisecondsTimeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait()
 at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Internal.KestrelEngine.CreateServer(ServerAddress address)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.KestrelServer.Start[TContext](IHttpApplication`1 application)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost.Start()
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.WebHostExtensions.Run(IWebHost host, CancellationToken token, String shutdownMessage)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.WebHostExtensions.Run(IWebHost host)
at Exactor.XeroConnector.API.Program.Main(String[] args)
```

The main problem is that the error is not reproduce on my local machine but only when the image is build and upload via Jenkins.
Can you please someone advise with it.

Comment: Ho do you specify host and port, where your app is running?

Comment: I tried to add also
      .UseUrls("http://*:60000")
but the error is still the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tnx for the answer the problem was that Jenkins somehow is not publish the latest image....